# Unable to install with admin

Tags: macos, command-line, mysql, open-source

I am trying to update [MAMP MySQL](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/07/how-to-use-mysql-5-6-with-mamp-and-mamp.html) from this link, but when i double click the file as mentioned in the blog. I get message saying,

> The file “Install_MySQL_5.6.25.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges.

I tried to see the rights **Get Info** and it shows i am the owner and i have read and write. 
If i am the owner, why can't i install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file might not be marked executable. Try this:

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Enter: "chmod u+x " (without the quotes but with the space) but don't press enter yet

3.Drop the "Install_MySQL_5.6.25.command" file on the Terminal.app window. 
The full path to "Install_MySQL_5.6.25.command" should appear.

4. Press enter

The file is now marked as executable and you should be able to run it.

Comment: It says cannot execute binary file

Comment: Try typing: file <drop the .command file on the window>

it will show you what kind of file it is. Where did you get the file? Can you supply a link or the first few lines of the file?

Comment: I got the [link](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/07/how-to-use-mysql-5-6-with-mamp-and-mamp.html) from here

Comment: Looks like the file might simply not be executable yet. I have updated my answer to account for that. Make sure the file is unzipped too!