# Cannot execute this binary file

Tags: terminal, mysql, zip, mamp

appreciate any assistance, I'm a Mac Noob

Im trying to upgrade MySQL in MAMP to 5.6 according to the [these instructions](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/07/how-to-use-mysql-5-6-with-mamp-and-mamp.html)

When I try to run the .command script as per #2 I get the following output:

```
Sandies-MacBook:~ sandie$ /Users/sandie/Downloads/Install_MySQL_5.6.25.command ; exit;
-bash: /Users/sandie/Downloads/Install_MySQL_5.6.25.command: cannot execute binary file
```

I have [found this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225985/unable-to-install-with-admin/225991#225991?newreg=a80c19ee3a4841b6b72954ebe522cdab), but I still get the "Cannot Execute" error.  I checked the file type as per the instructions, and the result is:

Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

The instructions suggest I need to unzip it but I have no idea how?

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remote/delete the downloaded file
2. Download it again, it should get a `.zip` extension
3. Double-click the downloaded file to unpack it
4. In Terminal, run

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   chmod +x Install_MySQL_5.6.25.command
   ./Install_MySQL_5.6.25.command
   ```

Comment: Fabulous, thanks for your help!  Now on to the next problem :)